# Reading a file, block per block

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, pipe

I'm trying to make an efficient script to read a (big) file block per block, and save the first line of the last read block in a file.
In my case, this is very useful if I want to pipe a file to a program. I can stop it and start it later at the same line it has been stopped before (meaning the same block line).

Here is the script :

```
LINE_FILE=line-file
READ_FILE=the_file
BLOCK=1000
LN_SUP=$(cat $LINE_FILE)

####

trap "save_line ; exit" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM SIGKILL

save_line()
{
    echo $LN_SUP > $LINE_FILE
}

block_cat()
{
    TEXT=$(tail -n+$LN_SUP $READ_FILE | head -n $BLOCK)
    echo "$TEXT"
    if [ -n "$TEXT" ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return -1
    fi
}

test()
{
    return 1
}

file_cat()
{
    >&2 echo "First line to read the file : $LN_SUP"
    block_cat $READ_FILE
    while [ $? -eq 0 ]; do
        LN_SUP=$(($LN_SUP + $BLOCK))  #Remember the new first line of the block
        block_cat $READ_FILE
    done
}
```

This is actually working, but not as fast as I was expecting.

This is used to pipe the output to aircrack-ng, and I loose almost 18% of efficiency.

Do you think there is a better way to do this ?

Comment: Not opening the file and repeatedly seeking through it would likely help. Unfortunately doing that in bash isn't exactly possible unless you want to read sequentially from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will do:

```
#!/bin/bash

line_file=line-file
quantum=1000
file=the_file

die() {
    (($#)) && printf '%s\n' "$@"
    exit 1
}

[[ -e $line_file ]] || echo "0" > "$line_file"
[[ -f $line_file ]] || die "File \`$line_file' not found"
[[ -r $line_file ]] || die "Can't read file \`$line_file'"

read current_line < "$line_file"

[[ $current_line = *([[:digit:]]) ]] || die "Error in file \`$line_file'"
((current_line=10#$current_line))

callback() {
    printf '%s\n' "${mary[@]}"
    mary=()
    echo "$1" > "$line_file"
}

mapfile -O "$current_line" -s "$current_line" -t -c "$quantum" -C callback mary < "$file" && callback
```

It uses `mapfile` and its rarely used (and not well-known) callback and quantum stuff. Don't be surprised if the first block is only 999 lines. The other ones are 1000 lines long. There are workarounds for this, but I don't think it's very important in your case.

I haven't really tried it, let me know if there are any flaws.

There are many useless lines in here regarding your original question. But eh, these are just error handling and routine check that can't hurt. You can concentrate on this only:

```
callback() {
    printf '%s\n' "${mary[@]}"
    mary=()
    echo "$1" > "$line_file"
}

mapfile -O "$current_line" -s "$current_line" -t -c "$quantum" -C callback mary < "$file" && callback
```

So each time `quantum` (here 1000) lines are read, the callback is called, with first parameter set to the array's index that will be set after the callback. In this call back, we just dump the content of the array, clear this array, and save the position of the file in `line_file`. It's that simple. To get the end of the file, we'll call `callback` one last time.

When `mapfile` is executed, `-s "$current_line"` tells `mapfile` to skip that many lines, and `-O "$current_line"` tells `mapfile` to start assigning at this index.

Comment: It works like a charm ! mapfile just do the work perfectly. Note that I adapted the quantum to a higher value (10000).